# How to open a webpage and search for a word in python

Tags: python, http

How to open a webpage and search for a word in python?

Answer (score 4):

This is a little simplified:

```
>>> import urllib
>>> import re
>>> page = urllib.urlopen("http://google.com").read()

# => via regular expression

>>> re.findall("Shopping", page)
['Shopping']

# => via string.find, returns the position ...
>>> page.find("Shopping")
2716
```

First, get the page (e.g. via [`urllib.urlopen`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen)). Second use a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) to find portions of the text, you are interested in. Or use [`string.find`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.find).

Comment: Not much point using `re.compile` if you're not saving the compiled regexp to a variable. `re.findall("Shopping", page)` is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

you can use urllib2

```
import urllib2

webp=urllib2.urlopen("the_page").read()

webp.find("the_word")
```

hope that helps :D

Answer (score 0):

How to open a webpage?

I think the most convinient way is:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen

page = urlopen('http://www.example.com').read()
```

How to search for a word?

I guess you are going to search for some pattern in the page next, so here we go:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('^some regex$')
match = pattern.search(page)
```