# urlopen not working for specific url

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, urlopen

Hello everyone I am pretty new to programming so please forgive me any noob mistakes.
I am trying to use **urllib** in **python 3.6** to find a string on a webpage and the solution I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1913871/how-to-open-a-webpage-and-search-for-a-word-in-python) is working great for most webpages i tested, for example:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
>>>string = 'google'
>>>url = 'https://google.com/'
>>>webp=urlopen(url).read()
>>>isfound = webp.find(string.encode('utf-8'))
>>>print(isfound)
186
```

But when I try using the URL https://chan.sankakucomplex.com/ (NSFW) I get tons of errors and I don't know why.
I allready tried changing my DNS to 8.8.8.8 but this didn't change anything.

error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1318, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 1392, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\http\client.py", line 936, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socket.py", line 704, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\socket.py", line 743, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/-/Desktop/python/searcher/stackex.py", line 5, in <module>
    webp=urlopen(url).read()
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\-\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>`

Comment: are you perhaps in a country or in some network that blocks this content?

Comment: Your code works on my machine (with your website and the string "sankaku". [Similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35835767/urllib-error-urlerror-urlopen-error-errno-11002-getaddrinfo-failed).

Comment: Thank you! I forgot I needed to use my proxy to access the site. Any idea how I get urllib to use my SOCKS5 proxy? This http://dae.me/blog/1959/using-pythons-urllib2-or-requests-with-a-socks5-proxy/ doesn't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
```

This tells me that your DNS server is refusing to translate the text address (chan.sankakucomplex.com) into an IP address.  It's not an issue with Python.

Can you get to that site from a web browser running on the same machine where you're running your python code?

Comment: Thank you! I forgot I needed to use my proxy to access the site. Any idea how I get urllib to use my SOCKS5 proxy? This http://dae.me/blog/1959/using-pythons-urllib2-or-requests-with-a-socks5-proxy/ doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: not sure about urllib.  But you'll have a much easier life if you start using requests (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/)